# Terrafrom - Deploy to multiple azure subscriptions

Tags: azure, terraform, subscription, terraform-provider-azure

I have been trying to use the same terraform stack to deploy resources in multiple azure subscriptions.  Also need to pass parameters between these resources in different subscriptions.  I had tried to use multiple Providers, but that is not supported.

```
Error: provider.azurerm: multiple configurations present; only one configuration is allowed per provider
```

If you have a way or an idea on how to accomplish this please let me know.

Comment: launch each terraform process in a separate container?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use multiple providers by using `alias` ([doku](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#multiple-provider-instances)).

```
# The default provider configuration
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxx"
}

# Additional provider configuration for west coast region
provider "azurerm" {
  alias  = "y"
  subscription_id = "yyyyyyyyyyy"
}
```

And then specify whenever you want to use the alternative provider:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "network_x" {
  name     = "production"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "network_y" {
  provider = "azurerm.y"
  name     = "production"
  location = "West US"
}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks Markus & @giulio-vian

Comment: Hii @Markus...I was working on a problem and faced a similar issue, which I could solve by your approach, so thanks. Also thanks Parvez, for asking the question. I just wanted to ask just like any other resource if I wish to assign policies to multiple subscriptions in azure and am prepared to use more than one assignment block but only a single policy_set_definition block then can it done ? ( using this technique of multiple providers, using a single definition block ? )

Comment: Hi @SwarnabjaBhaumik: To gain better help, please ask a separate question showing your efforts to solve and provide initial code samples. I'm glad that this answer helped you out.

Comment: Hii @Markus, thanks. As you suggested, I have asked a separate question, pertaining to my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Markus answer is correct, but it is the right solution *if* you need to access more than one subscription in the same set of Terraform sources.

If your purpose is to use one subscription as sandbox and the other for real, you should simply move the provider information out of Terraform scripts. There are more than one way to manage this:

- [Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html)
- [Backend configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html)
- A wrapper script in bash/Powershell/python in [Terragrunt](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt) style
- Symbolic links can also be used to share files in multiple folders

I use a combination of the last three as workspaces are too rigid for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error code for a silly reason as a Terraform beginner, maybe someone here has the same problem:

I saved a backup of my `main.tf` file as something like `mymainbackup1.tf` and Terraform interpreted it as a real .tf file even though it wasn't `main.tf`, therefore it thought I had more than one provider registered.

I changed the file to the .txt extension and Terraform stopped interpreting that file and stopped giving the error.