# Terraform repo structure for multiple clients using common modules and GitHub actions workflow

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I have the following repository structure planned:

```
Repo
  |
  - Modules
   -- Mod1
   -- Mod2
  |
  - ClientSection-1
   -- Main.tf
   -- variables.tf
  |
  - ClientSection-2
   -- Main.tf
   -- variables.tf
  |
  .
  .
  - ClientSection-N 
   -- Main.tf
   -- variables.tf
```

and I would like to use GitHub actions to build the various environments for the clients.
All clients share the same modules and when code is committed to the module portion of the repository, all clients should be updated through the GitHub actions workflow at the repo level.
When code is committed to a specific client, only that client should be updated.

I'm in the process of learning GitHub actions but can't see how to accomplish this in the best way and I'm not sure whether I should build repositories for each client and referring in the GitHub actions to the module repository as a separate actions/checkout like this:

```
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    path: main

- name: Checkout tools repo
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    repository: my-org/modules
    path: modules
```

Or whether I'm missing the boat on something apparently better all together.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Whats wrong with just running terraform on all the clients even if changes happened in only one of them. Terraform should be idempotent so running the TF against client_section-1 to client_section-n, should only result in changes to the given client_section that changed. All other sections should report that the infrastucture has no changes and matches

Comment: While I agree with the idempotent argument you are making, I don't see how to implement it when clients are under separate Azure subscriptions etc. I'm also stumped on how to accomplish this. Do I now need a separate "driver" section with which I call all the others in turn? Sorry for my ignorance in this.

Comment: maybe have a look at something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714639/terrafrom-deploy-to-multiple-azure-subscriptions it shows how you can have different aliases of the same provider.